# Characteristics of the Milne Problem on a Finite Slab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde, transport-equation

I'm trying to justify equation (3.43) on page 18 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2583.pdf) by Lei Wu and Yan Guo on diffusion approximation of the radiative transport equation.

Consider the following penalized transport equation:

$$\begin{cases}
\lambda f_\lambda + \sin\phi\frac{\partial f_\lambda}{\partial\eta} + F(\eta)\cos\phi\frac{\partial f_\lambda}{\partial\phi} + f_\lambda = H(\eta,\phi)\\
f_\lambda(0,\phi) = h(\phi) & \text{ for }\sin\phi < 0\\
f_\lambda(L,\phi) = f_\lambda(L,-\phi).
\end{cases}$$

Assume everything is as nice as necessary;  in particular, $h$ and $H$ are bounded. Here $\eta\in[0, L]$ and $\phi\in S^1$. Now let $V(\eta)$ be a function such that $F(\eta) = -\partial_\eta V(\eta)$.

Let $\mathbf{x}(s) = (\phi(s),\eta(s))$ be the characteristic curve corresponding to the PDE. Using the method of characteristics, we deduce that the characteristic curve $\mathbf{x}(s)$ satisfies $\mathbf{\dot{x}}(s) = (\phi'(s),\eta'(s))= (F(\eta(s)\cos\phi(s), \sin\phi(s))$. Simple computation shows that along this curve, the quantity $\cos(\phi(s))e^{-V(\eta(s))} \equiv E$ remains constant. This proves (3.42) in the paper.

The authors then claim  that along such a curve, the equation can be simplified as follows:
$$\lambda f_\lambda + \sin\theta\frac{\partial f_\lambda}{\partial \eta} + f_\lambda = H.$$
**It's not clear to me how this follows.** Indeed, along the characteristics, we have $\cos\phi = Ee^{-V(\eta(s))}$, but plugging this back into the original PDE doesn't get rid of the $\frac{\partial f_\lambda}{\partial\phi}$ term.

Comment: note: this has been cross-posted in MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369864/l-infty-transport-equation-estimate-characteristics-of-the-milne-problem-on)